# How to accomplish this byte munging in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

#### Background:

I'm trying to use the perl script from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/perl-scripts-to-encrypt-decrypt-adb-backup-files.1730309/) to decrypt an android backup. Unfortunately, the checksum validation fails.

After playing around with [this (Python) script](https://github.com/lclevy/ab_decrypt/blob/master/ab_decrypt.py), the problem seems to be that I need to do some additional munging of the master key (n.b. `masterKeyJavaConversion` in the Python script).

#### Problem:

I need to take a bag of bytes and perform the following conversion steps:

- Sign-extend from signed char to signed short
- Convert the result from UTF16 (BE?) to UTF-8

For example (all bytes are in hex):

- 3x → 3x
- 7x → 7x
- ax -> ef be ax
- bx -> ef be bx
- cx -> ef bf 8x
- dx -> ef bf 9x
- ex -> ef bf ax
- fx -> ef bf bx

(The `x` always remains unchanged.)

More specifically, given a bit sequence `1abc defg`, I need to output `1110 1111 1011 111a 10bc defg`. (For `0abc defg`, the output is just `0abc defg`, i.e. unchanged.)

---

Answers may use UTF conversions or may do the bit twiddling directly; I don't care, as long as it works (this isn't performance-critical). Answers in the form of a subroutine are ideal. (My main problem is I know just enough Perl to be dangerous. If this was C/C++, I wouldn't need help, but it would be a major undertaking to rewrite the entire script in another language, or to modify the Python script to not need to read the entire input into memory.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1110 1111 1011 111a 10bc defg` would be a valid UTF-8 encoding.

```
++++-------------------------- Start of three byte sequence
||||     ++------------------- Continuation byte
||||     ||       ++---------- Continuation byte
||||     ||       ||
11101111 1011111a 10bcdefg
    ||||   ||||||   ||||||
    ++++---++++++---++++++---- 1111 1111 1abc defg
```

That's just the extension of an 8-bit signed number to 16 bits, cast to unsigned, and treated as a Unicode Code Point.

So, without looking at the code, I think you want

```perl
sub encode_utf8 { 
   my ($s) = @_;
   utf8::encode($s);
   return $s;
}

sub munge {
   return
      encode_utf8                # "\x30\x70\xEF\xBE\xA0..."
         pack 'W*',              # "\x{0030}\x{0x0070}\x{0xFFA0}..."
            unpack 'S*',         # 0x0030, 0x0070, 0xFFA0, ...
               pack 's*',        # "\x30\x00\x70\x00\xA0\xFF..." (on a LE machine)
                  unpack 'c*',   # 48, 112, -96, ...
                     $_[0];      # "\x30\x70\xA0..."
}

my $s = "\x30\x70\xA0\xB0\xC0\xD0\xE0\xF0";
my $munged = munge($s);
```

If you remove the comments, you get the following:

```perl
sub munge {
   my $s = pack 'W*', unpack 'S*', pack 's*', unpack 'c*', $_[0];
   utf8::encode($s);
   return $s;
}
```

---

Here's a much [faster](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/631b928e0d786640001c0d52606bbb57) solution:

```perl
my @map = (
   ( map chr($_),            0x00..0x7F ),
   ( map "\xEF\xBE".chr($_), 0x80..0xBF ),
   ( map "\xEF\xBF".chr($_), 0xC0..0xFF ),
);

sub munge { join '', @map[ unpack 'C*', $_[0] ] }
```

Comment: Yeah, no need to look at the context. If I wanted to rewrite that so I can invoke it like `$munged = munge($s)`, though, how would I do that?

Comment: Uh... what's the `...`? I'm not sure I explained clearly; I want the pack/unpack chain inside the sub, not at the call site.

Comment: Yup, the "also written as" version is nicer; thanks!

Comment: Revert if you want; I won't be offended (it's annoying that once you have a certain rep you can't propose edits any more); I usually assume most folks just don't bother (or even know about) glyphs they can't easily type. One might think most folks would have functional Unicode by now, though...

Answer (score 2):

This may not be as elegant as [ikegami](/users/589924)'s [answer](/a/65468326/1644352), but it worked:

```perl
sub munge_mk
{
  my $out;
  foreach(unpack('C*', $_[0])) {
    if($_ < 128) {
     $out .= chr($_);
    } else {
     my $hi = 0xbc | (($_ & 0xc0) >> 6);
     my $lo = 0x80 | ($_ & 0x3f);
     $out .= chr(0xef) . chr($hi) . chr($lo);
    }
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: The difference in performance might be more important than in elegance.

Comment: @choroba Mine is more than twice as fast (if you inline the UTF-8 encoding). [Benchmark](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/631b928e0d786640001c0d52606bbb57). Both solutions create a comparable number of scalars, but Matthew's solution has way more Perl operations. They add up to a lot more than parsing the relatively simple pack language in C.

Comment: @choroba, if this needed to run on more than ~100 bytes, you might have a point. In practice, performance is *massively* dominated by the AES decryption, with the key checksum validation being an unnoticeable blip. OTOH, elegance is nice too...

Comment: @choroba, I had high hopes for a regex-based solution, but the best I could find (`$_[0] =~ s{([\x80-\xBF])|[\xC0-\xFF]}{ ( defined($1) ? "\xEF\xBE" : "\xEF\xBF" ) . $& }rge`) is slower than the existing solutions.

Comment: @choroba, WOW! Even using a precomputed mapping (`join "", map $map[$_], unpack 'C*', $_[0]`) is slower than my the posted solution (though faster than Matthew's)! How is that possible?!

Comment: @ikegami: I don't know, but from my experience, pack/unpack tends to be the fastest possible.

Comment: @choroba, It's `map` that was slowing things down. You know what blows my previous solution out of the water? `join "", @map[ unpack 'C*', $_[0] ]` It's 5x the speed of Matthew's